# Magento not recognizing theme package `rwd`

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, rwd-theme

I updated a Magento install from 1.3 to 1.9 and worked out most of the kinks (getting the page to display required indexing site, etc)

But it is not recognizing the rwd theme package

It sees the package (it will let me set the package as default).. if you try and use a package that does not exist the config will not save, but it is not using the theme in the front end

compilation is disabled
version is 1.9.1

### Update

I am an idiot, the cms pages all had a default template set (not sure why or how), so this was a non issue

Comment: stating the obvious, did you disable cache? Are the file rights and owner correct on the RWD files?

Comment: Yes, caching is disabled and as far as I know all permissions are correct, I ran the update from 1.3 - 1.4, then 1.4 - 1.9 via command line, would it create inaccessible files?

Just checked, same owner/group as all other site files

Comment: depends on how you're logged on on SSH

Comment: As said above, the same owner/group as the rest of the site files, and compared to a different Magento install the same file permissions as the other install

Comment: A bit of a silly question, but are you sure a different theme isn't set on a website or store view scope? (it happens)

Comment: Checked that first, all site views are set to default `rwd`